# How to change the value of property of object which is inside the array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of property of object which is inside the array and that array also inside one object.

I write below code to resolve issue however it take only last value.

my code

```js
var arr = [{
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry Fancy",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 6.205240232694746
    }]
  },
  {
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry USDA",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 5.622770183585882
    }]
  }
];

var value_a1 = null

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var result = arr[i].RATES;
  var QUALITYNAME = arr[i].QUALITYNAME;

  console.log("result", result);
  result.forEach((element, index) => {
    value_a1 = element.VALUE;
    value_a1 = parseFloat(value_a1.toFixed(2))
    console.log('value_a1', value_a1);
  });
}

arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  arr[index] = {
    QUALITYNAME: QUALITYNAME,
    RATES: {
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": value_a1
    }
  };
});

console.log(arr);
```

which give me output as

```
 result arr = [ { QUALITYNAME: 'Berry USDA',
        RATES: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'USD', VALUE: 5.62 } },
      { QUALITYNAME: 'Berry USDA',
        RATES: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'USD', VALUE: 5.62 } } ]
```

however I need it first value also to be there in result as below

```
 result arr = [ { QUALITYNAME: 'Berry Fancy',
        RATES: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'USD', VALUE: 6.21 } },
      { QUALITYNAME: 'Berry USDA',
        RATES: { UNIT: 'LB', CURRENCY: 'USD', VALUE: 5.62 } } ]
```

Please help me to correct this or give me some hint how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've taken the array from RATES, so what happens if you get more than one RATE in that list?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks like you're just replacing the `RATES` array with the last element of the array. Why do you need two loops for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the second loop after the first loop is done, so the variables `QUALITYNAME` and `rates_a1` have the values from the last iteration.

You can simply extract the object from the array and modify it in the first loop.

```js
var arr = [{
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry Fancy",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 6.205240232694746
    }]
  },
  {
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry USDA",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 5.622770183585882
    }]
  }
];

var value_a1 = null

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var result = arr[i].RATES[0];
  if (result) {
    result.VALUE = parseFloat(result.VALUE.toFixed(2));
  }
  arr[i].RATES = result;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you're just trying to round all rates to two decimals, you can achieve that with a nested loop like:

```js
var arr = [{
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry Fancy",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 6.205240232694746
    }]
  },
  {
    QUALITYNAME: "Berry USDA",
    RATES: [{
      "UNIT": "LB",
      "CURRENCY": "USD",
      "VALUE": 5.622770183585882
    }]
  }
]

// Loop through each array item
arr.forEach((item) => { 
    // Loop through each rate inside the item
    item.RATES.forEach((rate) => {
        // Round to two decimals
        rate.VALUE = parseFloat(rate.VALUE.toFixed(2))
    });
})
```

Comment: he also wants to turn the RATES array into a single object.

Comment: I interpreted "I write below code to resolve issue however it take only last value." as that's an issue with the current code. I thought he wanted to keep it as an array.

Comment: `arr` should still be an array, but `arr[i].RATES` should be an object.

Comment: Look at the desired result in the question.

Comment: The problem he has is that `arr[1].RATES` contains the VALUE from the original `arr[0].RATES`.